# Altitudes of a tetrahedron

Tags: geometry, vectors, analytic-geometry

Consider the following scenario.

The position vectors of the vertices A, B and C , of a tetrahedron are $(1,1,1),(1,0,0), (3,0,0)$ respectively. The altitude from the vertex D to the opposite face $\triangle ABC$ meets the median line through A of the $\triangle ABC$ at point E. The length of side AD is $4$ and
volume of the tetrahedron is $\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}$.

I am thinking that we get a unique tetrahedron here and thus a unique position for E

But using the fact that E divides AD in ratio say $k:1$ and that $\triangle AED$ is a right triangle. I am getting two values of $k$.

Is one of them an extra solution? If yes, how do I reject the extra one? If no, can you tell how two positions are possible.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm) to format your posts.  To begin with, surround math expressions (including numbers) with `$` signs and use `_` for subscripts.  `$x_1$` comes out as $x_1$.

Comment: I will keep that in mind

Comment: It is not clear what the tetrahedron volume is. That is why you need to use mathjax. Is it $\frac{2}{3\sqrt3}$ or $\frac{2\sqrt3}{3}$? Also what is that you are trying to find? Can you write that clearly? Is it just the altitude from $D$ to $\triangle ABC$?

Comment: if you think of $ABC$ plane, the vertex $D$ has two possible positions relative to the plane

Comment: $AE^2=AD^2-DE^2$. But $AD=4$ and $DE=\ $altitude$\ =\sqrt6$. Hence $AE^2=10$. Where is the other solution?

Comment: Of course point $E$ can be on either side of $A$, and $D$ can be on either side of plane $ABC$. Hence you have 4 possible tetrahedra.